# Enter incorrect password in Chrome, login dialog no longer popups

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, iis, cookies

1. Set the application with webapi in IIS as window authentication
2. Using ajax to access this webapi
3. The system popups the login dialog
4. I enter domain account and wrong password
   The strange thing is that the login dialog no longer popup, even I close and reopen it. Why chrome does not give me a chance to correct the wrong password? But IE could work.
   I find the chrome contains a cookie with empty, without key and value when I debug it. If I delete it (by Chrome -- setting -- Privacy and security -- Clear browsing data), then it works again.

So, my question is how to delete this cookie by JS? or any other idea? It will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You could set below browser setting to ask always login credential:

1. Open the Internet Explorer and click the settings icon, and then select the ‘Internet Options’.

[image]

2. Select the ‘Security’ tab in the pop-up window.

[image]

3. Choose the “Local intranet” and choose the “Custom level

[image]

4. Prompt Settings

   - Select “Prompt for user name and password” under “Logon” for the
     Internet Explorer to prompt for getting the credentials from the user.
   - Select “Automatic logon with current user name and password” for the
     Internet Explorer to automatically log on as the currently logged
     user

[image]

Restart the Internet Explorer to apply the prompt settings.

for chrome:

- Click the Chrome menu three dots in the toolbar and choose Settings.
- Click Passwords.
- Turn off "Auto Sign-in"

[image]

if you want to use js then you could try below code:

```
    function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

OR

```
function removeCookies() {
        var res = document.cookie;
        var multiple = res.split(";");
        for(var i = 0; i < multiple.length; i++) {
           var key = multiple[i].split("=");
           document.cookie = key[0]+" =; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
        }
     }
```

Comment: I did the browser setting as you mentioned above. But it does not work for chrome, and only enter incorrect password. And this cookie cannot be delete, maybe it is httpOnly type.

Comment: @JoeyWang did you try to disable auto sign-in a setting? also, make sure you deleted your username and password from the setting.